# Set title equal to variable to Web Panel in Genexus

Tags: genexus

What I want to do is simple, I have a variable that is loaded on Start and I want the page of the page to be equal to this variable. I tried the three following approaches:

[image: Set variable to description]

[image: Set variable to description naked]

[image: Use these variables]

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bruno.

Use:

Form.caption = &Puntonombre

In the start event.